# ASP.Net Create User Control with Strong Password

Tags: asp.net, winforms, asp.net-membership

I need a control that will accept an email address and password/verify with a password strength indicator.

Has anyone seen a similar type control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [PasswordStrength](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/PasswordStrength/PasswordStrength.aspx) control from the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

check this article which use google api to create password strenth control :

(Google Password Strength API)
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/GooglePasswordStrength.aspx